# Visual Studio 2013 Remote Profiler

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, profiling

I have just installed Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2013 on my production server and can attach a debugger to it from my development machine without any problems.  Great feature to have, but what I can't figure out how to do is attach a profiler to the production machine via the Performance and Diagnostics screen in VS2013.  Is there a way to do this?

P.S. - I know that JetBrains DotTrace offers remote profiling, but am specifically looking to see if VS offers this functionality built in.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, (sadly) VS 2013 is able to debug remote applications but not to profile them.

I answered to a similar question with more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30234332/214517).

Answer (score 0):

We currently support remote profiling of Windows Store Applications. Is this the kind of remote profiling you were looking for?

Comment: No I'm afraid not - I'm wanting to profile a WCF service deployed on my production server.

Comment: Sorry about that, will make a note of it for us to consider. If you have access to the remote machine you could use our command line tools to profile, but you might get a bit of noise depending on how it is done. Is that an option