# Does Visual Studio 2015 Community support remote profiling?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi2

My system:

Server: Windows 10 Pro 1511 10586.36 Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community 14.0.24720.00 Update 1

Client: Windows 10 IoT Core (build 10586) Raspberry Pi 2.

My question:

I would like to profile C++ native application on Raspberry Pi 2.
But i was unable to find how exactly to do it.
Default profiling launch wizard works ok when using the application which is deployed locally but doesn't work for the case when application deployed remotely.

Here is the link [Visual studio 2012 profiling remotely debugged process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780558/visual-studio-2012-profiling-remotely-debugged-process) which is about VS 2012 actually, but it seems that even for 2015 problem is the same.

So is there a direct way to use VS remote profiling tool similar to the local one?