# Visual Studio 2012 Performance Profiler attach to a remote process

Tags: visual-studio-2012, performance-testing

I am trying to debug performance issues on a Virtual Machine. Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio 2012?

In Debug > Attach To Process you can attach processes from a VM to do debugging. I can't see a similar option on Analyze > Profiler > Attach/Detach option..

Is there any way to enable this? Are there any free similar profiling tools?

note: I can install VS 2012 on the VM, just hoping there's an easier way..

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio allows remote debugging but **not remote profiling**.

I would install [Visual studio standalone profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385771.aspx) X86 or X64 depending on target architecture that comes with visual studio DVD onto virtual machine, run commands to attach Profiler, navigate applicaiton scenario to be debugged, Generate visual studio performance file(VSP or VSPX)(do not forget to pack symbols)

Copy VSP or VSPX file to your DEV PC and find the hot spots!

Credit due where credit deserved:
[Visual studio 2012 profiling remotely debugged process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780558/visual-studio-2012-profiling-remotely-debugged-process)

Comment: Please add some detail from the link in our answer. Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to remote profile in vs 2022?

Answer (score 1):

can't check VS2012 but VS2105 has this
Debug->Profiler->Performance explorer->Attach